# Xcode control size of image in UIButton

Tags: xcode, uibutton

I have an UIButton with no text on it. It just has an image which I want to be shown in the middle of the button at the maximal available size.

However, the image is only shown very small in the middle of my button (the button fills nearly the whole screen)

I cannot find a property in Xcode where I can change the image size. I could only set it as background image but then it is not stretched proportionally and looks very strange....

Is there a way to do it in the interface builder or do I have to write some code? If yes, any hints where to start? I use Swift.

Comment: Use a bigger image. Scaling a small image up to screen size will make it look really pixelated and blurry.

Comment: But I cannot provide an image for all possible screen resolutions. What I really would like to have is an image that is shown as large as possible in the middle of the button without being stretched. Is this possible without implementing a custom button class?